# What are the best sources to find news about PHP, Zend Framework, JavaScript security issues

Tags: php, zend-framework, dojo

What are the best sources to find news about PHP, Zend Framework, JavaScript security issues and fixes?

So far i have located:

[PHP Updates](http://www.php.net/feed.atom),  [Zend Framework security](http://framework.zend.com/security/feed) , [Zend Framework updates](http://devzone.zend.com/tag/Zend_Framework_Management/format/rss2.0)

But i cant find something for our Frontend Frameworks like JQuery and Dojo. Is there no security problem with this kind of frameworks?

If i search google for something like "dojo or jquery" security are the only some short advises (-:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have basicly listed most of the good sources. But alot of information about vulnerabilities can be found at

http://cve.mitre.org/

http://www.cvedetails.com/

http://www.securityfocus.com/

etc

They cover a lot more but you can filter for what you are interested in.

For example, a list of PHP vulnerabilities can be found at [CVE details when searching for product PHP](http://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-74/product_id-128/PHP-PHP.html)

Answer (score 0):

RSS feeds are a convenient way of tracking news. List of RSS feeds provided by Zend can be seen on following link.

http://www.zend.com/en/rss-feeds